# soapAction attribute in WSDL operation is empty

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

There is a web service with the following WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://fer2.klab/notify" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://fer2.klab/notify" targetNamespace="http://fer2.klab/notify">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:er="http://fer2.klab/notify" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://fer2.klab/notify">
    <xs:element name="ServiceRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="HL7message" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ServiceResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="response" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ServiceResponse" name="ServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ServiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ServiceRequest" name="ServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="NotifyPort">
    <wsdl:operation name="Service">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ServiceRequest" name="ServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ServiceResponse" name="ServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="NotifyPortSoap11" type="tns:NotifyPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Service">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input name="ServiceRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="ServiceResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="NotifyPortService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:NotifyPortSoap11" name="NotifyPortSoap11">
      <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.101:8080/fer2-0.0.1/ws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

There is an endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class NotifyEndPoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URL = "http://fer2.klab/notify";

    @Autowired
    MainController mainController;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URL, localPart = "ServiceRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ServiceResponse send(@RequestPayload ServiceRequest hlMessage){
        System.out.println("notify method");
        Object resp = mainController.notify(null, "", hlMessage.getHL7Message());
        ServiceResponse sr = new ServiceResponse();
        if (resp != null){
            sr.setResponse(resp.toString());
        }
        else{
            sr.setResponse("null");
        }

        return sr;
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="notify" name="notify" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <!--<property name="createSoap12Binding" value="true" />-->
    <property name="portTypeName" value="NotifyPort" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="/ws" />
    <property name="schema">
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
            <property name="xsd" value="notify.xsd" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://fer2.klab/notify" />
    <!--<property name="soapActions">-->
        <!--<props>-->
            <!--<prop key="ServiceRequest">http://fer2.klab/notify/ServiceRequest"</prop>-->
        <!--</props>-->
    <!--</property>-->
</bean>
```

application-config.xml:

```
<bean class="klab.backend.utils.MainConfig" id="mainConfig">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/main.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/build.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="true"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.JacksonView2HttpMessageConverter">

            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.KJsonMapper">
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<context:component-scan base-package="klab.fer2"/>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
</bean>

<bean class="klab.backend.controller.base.DefaultController"/>

<bean name="CorsFilter" class="klab.backend.filter.CorsFilter"/>
```

Why does `Service` operation in generated WSDL has empty attribute `soapAction`?

SOAP-request to URL http://192.168.1.101:8080/fer2-0.0.1/ws with following content:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:not="http://fer2.klab/notify">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <not:ServiceRequest>
         <not:HL7message>hdfghdfghdfgh</not:HL7message>
      </not:ServiceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

results in the following error logged:

```
 org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound- No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://fer2.klab/notify}ServiceRequest]
```

Comment: You can use Metro or Axis Implementation to build SOAP based web services.

Found some example here 
http://www.expertwebindia.com/how-to-create-soap-based-web-service-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was finally solved.

WSDL was autogenerated and made static.

Endpoint was changed like this (the main point here is `@Action` annotation):

```
@Endpoint
public class NotifyEndPoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URL = "http://fer2.klab/notify";

    @Autowired
    MainController mainController;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URL, localPart = "ServiceRequest")
    @Action("http://fer2.klab/notify/ServiceRequest")
//    @ResponsePayload
    public void send(@RequestPayload ServiceRequest hlMessage) {
        System.out.println("notify method");
        mainController.notify(null, "", hlMessage.getHL7Message());
    }

}
```

`dispatcher-servlet.xml` changed to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="notify" name="notify" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
        <property name="wsdl" value="notify.wsdl" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="klab.fer2"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `soapAction` attribute of the `soap:operation` element is the value that will be included in the HTTP request message, as in:

```
POST /StockQuote HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: nnnn
SOAPAction: "http://electrocommerce.org/abc#MyMessage"
```

As stated in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) this value only indicates the **intent** of which operation will be called and it's not normally used by the web services frameworks when creating the stubs.

A common pattern is to set it to empty string as in `<soap:operation soapAction=""` which means that the operation that the request is referring to is indicated inside the http request's payload. So your wsdl looks fine in that regard.

In [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-mapping) though, you can annotate a method with `@SoapAction` and that method will be mapped using the soapAction header. But you are using `@PayloadRoot` on your method, so it will be mapped using the local name 'ServiceRequest', therefore the value of the soapAction will be `""` and it will not be used.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked only (spring-boot app):

[Resolve empty soapAction](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-ws-addressing-action-example/)

**wsdl11Definition.setSoapActions(soapActions);**

```
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean(name = "someService")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    ....

    Properties soapActions = new Properties();
    for (Method method : endpointController.class.getMethods() ) {
        soapActions.setProperty(method.getName(), Const.NAMESPACE_URI + "/#" + method.getName());
    }
    wsdl11Definition.setSoapActions(soapActions);

    return wsdl11Definition;
}
```